# How to remove unstaged changes [newline characters difference] in git?

Tags: git

This is frustrating and I simply can't find the right answer on how to handle this.
I am after a rebase [but this is just one of many scenarios where this problem occurs] and I have a ton of files "changed but not updated" that have no difference but for the newline characters.

```
git diff -b
```

nothing returned.

Now I just want to remove the changes and leave files as they are in the repo.
I've found plenty of "solutions":

1 Stashing changes
a) with --keep-index [this was actually from SO]

```
$ git stash save --keep-index
Saved working directory and index state WIP on COM-23: 4a8abc1 COM-23 changed pa
ckage name
HEAD is now at 4a8abc1 COM-23 changed package name

$ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (7d822e3c6bdc310f4a4be90ed937dd0ea97df627)

$ git status
[tons of files marked as changed but not updated]
```

b) without --keep-index
exactly the same as with 'a'

2 git reset
a) just a reset

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

same as above

b) with add

```
git add -A
git reset --hard HEAD
```

same as above

3 checkout

```
git checkout
```

same as above, status returns a lot of unstaged files.

I am quite certain I am doing something wrong or just misunderstanding the problem, but all I want to do is to get rid of the unstaged changes! 
How can I do that?

Thanks,
Krystian

Comment: Check out `git config core.autocrlf`. It's best to have it set to `false`. You may still need a `git reset --hard` after changing that value, because you have to sync your editor newlines settings with those of Git.

Comment: That's it! Put it as an answer and I'll happily mark it as I believe I am not the only one who has that config item broken!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out `git config [--global] core.autocrlf`. It's best to have it set to `false`. You may still need a `git reset --hard` after changing that value, because you have to sync your editor newlines settings with those of Git.

Answer (score 0):

Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.

Do like this.

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

and if you want to remove this changes completely then drop the stash

```
git stash drop
```